# Why is my custom class crashing upon attempting to save it in a property list?

Tags: swift, nscoding

I have the following class that conforms to `NSObject` and `NSCoding`:

```
class PredicPair: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var weight : Float
    var prediction : String

    init(weight: Float, prediction: String) {
        self.weight = weight
        self.prediction = prediction
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        weight = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weight") as! Float
        prediction = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "prediction") as! String
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(weight, forKey: "weight")
        aCoder.encode(prediction, forKey: "prediction")
    }
}
```

In another class, I create the following variable `words` of type `[String:[PredicPair]]` which I then try to save using `UserDefaults` with the following: `UserDefaults.standard.set(self.words, forKey: self.WordStoreKey())`. Upon runtime, I'm met with the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object
```

Why is that happening? Aren't I already conforming to NSCoding?

Comment: Implementing NSCoding is not sufficient, you have to *archive* the instances to `NSData` objects, which can be stored in the user defaults.

Comment: @MartinR I've also tried what's listed in the linked question and although the compiler no longer throws an error, the retrieved dictionary is empty. Any reason why?